# get position of opening parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I need to analyzing some code backwards and I am trying to get the position of the opening parenthesis, the problem is that inside the parenthesis there are more parenthesis, for example:

```
    customerPairs.leftOuterJoin(
            sc.textFile("C:/path/transactions_data.txt")
              .mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
                    public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) {
                        String[] transactionSplit = s.split(",");
                        return new Tuple2<String, String>(transactionSplit[2], transactionSplit[3]+","+transactionSplit[1]);
                        }
                    }))
            .groupByKey()
```

so after reading the groupByKey method and finding the first closing parenthesis I would like to know where it began (as Eclipse does, for example)

Comment: This aounds like maybe a parser would be a better tool here than regex.

Comment: If this is going to be run against any arbitrary code you will also need some way of identifying parentheses that are contained within a String or character literal so that you know to ignore them. As Tim alluded to, you're going to need a proper parser to do this.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like coursework...

Comment: That said, I'd perhaps look at using a stack, popping on closing parentheses as you encounter them and popping them off when you find a matching opening one (as you are analyzing backwards). Once the stack is empty, you should have hit your opening bracket. (Note: this only really works for well defined use cases (e.g. homework or coding interviews), otherwise you may have to do something about ignoring parentheses inside Strings or more complex exceptions) (Also note: this works nicely for handling brackets, braces and parentheses at once)

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* -- [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim is right. This should not be done by regex, but by a parser.
(By the way I don't think it is possible using regex).
With a parser you would have mainly two options:

1. You scan the whole string/file once and somehow connect the possitions of all parenthesis pairs. (For example by using a stack: each opening parenthesis pushes its location onto this stack and the closing parenthesis simply pops the top of the stack and "registers" this together with its own location as a pair").
2. You take the location of the parenthesis you want to know the partner of and walk through the code forwards or backwards (depening on the type of parenthesis you selected) and add up every parenthesis (+1 for an opening -1 for a closing parenthesis) until you meet one with is the contradiction of your selected one.

which one you should use depends on your needs/application.

PS: mind that if you have strings in between which might contain unpaired parenthesis you will have to make sure to ignore these strings

Hopefully that helps you.